# adjusting labels using bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place label in div as show in the figure.

Any idea how to show them inline and well alligned?

CODEPEN : [CODEPeN DEMO](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/AhEje)

Please look at two label:

1. `AUDI word wide -should Audi R8 named after SO?`
2. `wat more`
3. Button in right most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pull this off, i would use some CSS and DIVs to arrange everything inline. You don't really need the boostrap CSS syntax and classes, some good old CSS will do the job.

I would use a main DIV, named "item", which would act as the container for all my elements: image, label, hyperlink.

Next, using some CSS, i would start arranging all my elements next to each other, mainly by making them float. Since both hyperlinks will float right, i want to make sure that in my html, the "green pill button" is placed in front of the "Want More link", so that he really is displayed to the far right.

Anyway, that's one way to do it, might not be the best, but it works. If you resize the browser, everything follows inline. Of course, i would use some MediaQueries for mobile device width, but i'll leave that to you.

I hope this helps and that it answers your question!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tJxAT/)

Here what the full code would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.container{margin-top:50px;}
.item{background:#F3F3F3;height: 35px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}
.item img {-webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;float: left;}
.item .descriptionContainer{float: left;margin-left:45px;}
.item a {float: right;}
.item .pillBtn{-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;background:#7CDD97;padding: 5.5px 40px 5.5px 40px;color: #FFF;font-weight: bold;font-size: 17px;text-decoration: none;}
.item .moreBtn{position: relative;font-size: 12px;margin-right: 15px;margin-top: 15px;} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="item">
                <img class="media-object" src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/prod/image-slider-4.jpg" height="35">
                <div class="descriptionContainer">
                    <h6>Small description</h6>
                </div>
                <a class="pillBtn" href="#">78</a>
                <a class="moreBtn" href="#">want more?...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks was best answer I ever got :). for my info can you please introduce `MediaQueries ` little, though I am googling it.

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries is a CSS3 module that allows content to render and adapt itself to multiple screen resolution (e.g. smartphone and/or tablets vs. high definition screen).

A media query consists of a media type and one or more expressions, which resolve to either true or false. When a media query is true, the corresponding style sheet or style rules are applied. For example, an expression could evaluate if, let's say, the browser width correspond to a certain value, and if the answer is true, it would apply specific CSS rules you defined beforehand.

Bootstrap already makes use of media queries in order to resize page content, but you can expend these by defining your own.

```
/*Smartphones*/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /*Styles*/
    h1 { margin:0; margin-bottom: 25px; }
    p { width:350px; }
    /*etc etc etc...*/
}
```

Check out these links and read a bit, there are useful examples too. Happy coding!

[Source1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html)

[Source2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries)

[Source3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)